# An error appeared when I send test webhock to myapp on Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, stripe-payments

## An error appeared when I send test webhock to https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/webhock on Stripe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <status>500</status>
  <error>Internal Server Error</error>
</hash>
```

### Code

```
class WebhockController< ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: :create

 def create
   event = Stripe::Event.retrieve(params[:id])

   case event.type
   when 'customer.subscription.updated'
       subscription = event.data.object
        user = User.find_by(stripe_subscription_id: subscription.id)
        user.update_subscription(subscription)
   end
    head :ok
 end
end
```

// routes.rb

```
post "webhock"=>"webhock#create"
```

### Environment

- ruby 2.4
- Ruby on Rails4
- Heroku

  ### log

2017-06-14T12:56:32.470036+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 696ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: What does your heroku log say about the error?

Comment: there is nothing error in my heroku log.

Comment: The first thing to do when you see **any** error like this is to **look at the log**. Perhaps `Stripe::Event.retrieve(...)` failed? Perhaps `event.data.object` failed? Perhaps `User.find_by(..)` returned `nil`? There *will* be an error in the log; you must be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Anyway ,I know if there was nothing code,i could send test webhock to app ,and could  get some  responses from app through my experiment.

Comment: so i think heroku is wrong or rails's protect_from_forgery is wrong.

Comment: Off course, i checked my heroku log.

Comment: Are you telling me that **nothing** is being logged **anywhere**, when the rails app responds with a 500 error? I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: Sorry I mistook,I believed that activity is log.